# Changing the data type in java

Tags: java, types

The title seems common, but I can't find answers on other related questions. Our prof tasked to complete the source code he provided us. We are working on a phonebook. This phonebook have two separate classes namely `Contact` and `PhoneBook`. Here is the incomplete code for the `PhoneBook`.

```java
public class PhoneBook {

  Contact contact[] = new Contact[10];
  int size = 10, capacity = 0;

  public PhoneBook(int capacity) {
    capacity++;
  }

  public boolean add(Contact newContact) {
    if (capacity < 11) {
      contact[capacity] = newContact;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public boolean delete(Contact contact) {
    //fill-in code
    return false;
  }

  public boolean update(Contact oldContact, Contact updatedContact) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      // fill-in code
    }
    return found;
  }

  public Contact search(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
      // fill-in code
      // you may use the string.toLowerCase() and
      // string.equals(anotherstring) methods to check
      // the equality of two strings
    }
    return null;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return this.size;
  }

  public Contact[] getContacts() {
    return this.contacts;
  }

  public int getCapacity() {
    return this.capacity;
  }
}
```

My problem is the method `public Contact search(String name)`. We were told to check the equality of the strings in order to match the search of names in a phonebook, also to execute the delete method, updateContact and such. **But**, the variable `name` is a `String` type and the variable `contact` is a `Contact` type array. This is the contact class.

```java
public class Contact {

  String name;
  String contactNumber;

  public Contact(String name, String contactNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + ", Contact No: " + contactNumber;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return this.contactNumber;
  }
}
```

If I included the whole phonebook source code here it will be too long. I just need to compare `name` and `contact` but I can't because they are of different types. What shall I do?

Comment: Each `Contact` has a `String name`, you should compare *that*.

Comment: @luk2302 can I represent it as a variable?

Comment: You have swapped the meanings of capacity and size. “Capacity” means, how many elements can be stored, “size” means, how many elements are actually stored. Regardless of your naming, when you add an element, you have to increment the number of stored elements. Further, you shouldn’t use the legacy array syntax. The idiomatic form is `Contact[] contact = new Contact[10];` and you can always query the array length via `contact.length`, so there is no need to maintain another variable redundantly holding that number.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you create a contact, you will have something like this to instantiate a new contact object:

```
Contact contact = new Contact("Alice", contactNumber);
```

Also, in your class, you have a `getName()` method defined. If you assign a `otherName` variable, as follows, it will return the value `"Alice"` for you.

```
String otherName = contact.getName();
```

You can verify this by either debugging or by adding a print statement.

So to verify equality in these two objects, you can just run `name.equals(otherName)` which returns true or false.

However, since this is case-sensitive, you can instead use one of the following approaches:

- `name.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName)`
- `name.toLowerCase().equals(otherName.toLowerCase())`

In my opinion, the first is cleaner, but based on the comments you may have to use the latter, which I find less readable.

Another approach here would be: `Objects.equals(name.toLowerCase(), otherName.toLowerCase())`.

Comment: I think, the OP should use `equalsIgnoreCase` and tell the instructor that `toLowerCase` is a bad advice, so perhaps, at least one instructor may finally stop giving that advice. Not only is converting every string to a lowercase string before comparing less readable and quite expensive, it isn’t sufficient for case insensitive comparison. Consider `String s1 = "Σ", s2 = "ς";` then `s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2)` will correctly return `true` whereas `s1.toLowerCase().equals(s2.toLowerCase())` will return `false`.

Comment: I completely agree with you @Holger. The example was great.

Answer (score 1):

contact[i].name is a String type.
I guess you should to try this:

```
public Contact search(String name){
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
        if (contact[i].name.equals(name)) {
        ...your code...
        }
```

Don't forget ".toLowerCase()".

Comment: I'll update you later if this worked! I have to complete the whole code and run it thru a tester code. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to help you) write me if it doesn't work

Comment: Not `String::toLowerCase()` … instead the comparison should be `if( contact [i].name.equalsIgnoreCase( name ) ) …`

Comment: @tquadrat in the comments to the method, it is written to use toLowerCase, so I mention it. I agree that it will be easier to do equalsIgnoreCase through this, but we don't know full task condition

Comment: Hi @itfedorovsa. The warning disappeared now but I have another problem. I can't seem to call the ```search(name)``` method using other methods within the class. Like calling the ```search(name)``` method on the delete and update method in order to use it. I need to make it happen without changing the parameters tho

Comment: @Dexter1403 you can't call a method that accepts a parameter without this parameter. In which method are you going to call search(name)?

Comment: @itfedorovsa ```delete(contact)``` and ```update(oldContact, updatedContact)```

Comment: @Dexter1403 your methods accepts a "Contact". Contact have a fileld name. So use this field as a parameter. delete(contact) { ...search(contact.name)... }. Similarly in the update() method. These are all parameters that have a "name" field.